# What is the difference between writing onClick() in the XML file to writing listener with onClick function in the Java file?

Tags: java, android-studio

In Android you can write in button for example the `onClick()` function and linking the function to it. But most of the time I see people not doing it but activating `onClickListener` in the Java file to the button.
Why? What are the differences between the two? Are there cases when you are not allowed to use one of them?

Comment: From my personal experience, declaring `onClick` listeners in code, makes it much more readable - you can easily check where is the handling method called from, whereas when the handling method is only set in XML Android Studio even marks the method as unused.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Explanation:**

`onClick` via xml is good for `fixed` implementation in your code, but using `OnClickListener` is better for complex app structure with multiple UI elements or complex UI flow, but they both do the exact same thing.

**Detailed:**

when you set `onClick` via layout, LayoutInflator initiated by `setContentView`
pass this attribute to respected view constructor & managed by the views code.

But by using `OnClickListener` you can alter the behaviour of the control of click event management when it comes to complex app structure.

Below is snap of the internal implementation of `onClick` attribute

```
case R.styleable.View_onClick:
                    if (context.isRestricted()) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot "
                                + "be used within a restricted context");
                    }

                    final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
                    if (handlerName != null) {
                        setOnClickListener(new DeclaredOnClickListener(this, handlerName));
                    }
```

internal implementation itself uses `setOnClickListener`, so both are same,
as i mentioned above, using xml onClick option is good only when app is simple, otherwise use Listener.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally you are able to use either and they will both do the same thing. There is no restriction on which one you use, however many developers will favor using the Java code because it's a bit more flexible and allows you to add more functionality if you need to. Sometimes you might see people adding a very basic method call in the XML file which then links to a Java method doing everything they need.

All in all it's just a matter of preference and coding style.